# How to evaluate incomplete elliptic integrals?

Tags: integration, elliptic-integrals

From what I learned [here](https://www.wikihow.com/Evaluate-Complete-Elliptic-Integrals), for evaluating complete elliptic integrals, using the binomial theorem is quite effective as it puts the elliptic integral in the form of.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} some-constants\int_0^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{2n} \phi d\phi $$ which turns out to be easy to evaluate. Yet when it turns in to the form $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} some-constants\int_0^{\theta} \sin^{2n} \phi d\phi $$ which is quite common among elliptic integrals, I start to not know what to do. I resolved to go on with conducting a Taylor expansion where the derivatives(as I do not know how to evaluate the derivatives) I computed using Matlab. Yet what is the best way or the standard way(if there is such a way) to conduct/approximate these kinds of incomplete elliptic integrals?
As a reference, I want am trying to compute
$$ F(\dfrac{\theta + \gamma}{2}|\dfrac{2a}{a-1})$$

Comment: @Rohan Thanks for the comment! But isn't there a way to at least approximate it? I really will prefer to be able to do that.

Comment: @Rohan wait, then how do we find values associated with the incomplete elliptic integrals?

Comment: @Rohan I'm sorry for my persistence, yet when I inputted (in [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ellipticF(0.4,+0.5)) ) the elliptic integral EllipticF(0.4 | 0.5)  it returns the value 0.405352. It also returned a graph when I inputted a random elliptic function. So, I think it is possible.

Comment: @Rohan I am sorry for any mistakes I am making.

Comment: Sorry sir, I am wrong. See under the section [Connections within the group of incomplete elliptic integrals and with other function groups here](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticF/introductions/IncompleteEllipticIntegrals/ShowAll.html).

Comment: @Rohan, Thank you very much, Sir, (or Ma'am)! Hence, basically, if I use a thing called a hypergeometric function, will I be able to represent my elliptic integral with a numerical value? I am sorry for the abundance of questions.

Comment: Yes, definitely. By the way, I am a boy. Anyways, yes surely you can get a numerical value.

Comment: @Rohan Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

The modern way to compute incomplete elliptic integrals is via the [Carlson symmetric form](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlson_symmetric_form):
$$F(\varphi,m)=\sin\varphi R_F(\cos^2\varphi,1-m\sin^2\varphi,1)$$
$$R_F(x,y,z)=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{(t+x)(t+y)(t+z)}}\,dt$$
$R_F$ itself can be computed efficiently by a so-called duplication theorem, as detailed in the "Numerical evaluation" section of the linked Wikipedia article. The process is reminiscent of the AGM formula for computing complete elliptic integrals.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute $$y=F(x|k)$$ for small values of $k$ and $x$, you could use series expansion
$$y=\sum_{n=1}^p a_n\, x^{2n-1}+O(x^{2p+1})$$ where the first coefficients would be
$$a_1=1 \qquad a_2=\frac{k}{6}\qquad a_3=\frac{ k (9 k-4)}{120}\qquad a_4=\frac{k \left(225 k^2-180 k+16\right)}{5040}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Even if the values are not especially small, will the above trick still work?

Comment: I am sorry, a correction. "Will the trick above work?" is the correct wording